# Logging in with axios

Tags: node.js, axios

I am just starting with web scraping and using axios.

I am trying to take it one step at a time. I am trying to scrape a web page. There is a url for login page like

webpage/login

If I inspect the page the login form which has 2 input fields name and password,

```
<input type="text" name="login">
<input type="password" name="password">
```

Once I enter the username and password in the browser, I get redirected to a page which contains the data that I need.

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://mywebsite/login/',
    data: {
      login: 'Dave232',
      password: 'pass23456'
    }
  })
  .then(response=>{
    console.log(response.data)
    console.log(response.headers);
})
.catch(error=>{
    console.log(error)
})
```

However, when I run my node app, I get the login page html back instead of the next page.

```
console.log(response.header)
```

returns

```
{ date: 'Wed, 18 Sep 2019 03:17:35 GMT',
  server: 'Apache-Coyote/1.1',
  'content-type': 'text/html;charset=UTF-8',
  'content-length': '24979',
  'set-cookie':
   [ 'cfid=04d1704f-88f6-49b6-bcd4-4a7467b8e4ab;Path=/;Expires=Thu, 16-Sep-2049 11:09:05 GMT;HTTPOnly',
     'cftoken=0;Path=/;Expires=Thu, 16-Sep-2049 11:09:05 GMT;HTTPOnly',
     'JSESSIONID=6874842A05E89B0D8B1D33BEBAD537AF.NE1ITCPRHEWS06; Path=/website/; Secure; HttpOnly',
     'LOGGED_IN=;Path=/;Expires=Wed, 18-Sep-2019 03:17:35 GMT',
     'CF_CLIENT_WEBSITE=%7B%27queueLastTab%27%3A%27workorder%27%2C%27last_contract_category_sk%27%3A%27%27%7D;Path=/;Expires=Thu, 19-Sep-2019 03:17:35 GMT',
     'CF_CLIENT_WEBSITE_LV=1568776655537;Path=/;Expires=Thu, 19-Sep-2019 03:17:35 GMT',
     'CF_CLIENT_WEBSITE_TC=1568776655537;Path=/;Expires=Thu, 19-Sep-2019 03:17:35 GMT',
     'CF_CLIENT_WEBSITE_HC=2;Path=/;Expires=Thu, 19-Sep-2019 03:17:35 GMT' ],
  connection: 'close' }
```

Please help me.

Edit 1:

Just realized that the forms action preperty looks something like this:

```
<form action="index.cfm?fuseaction=security.login_check" method="post">
```

I have never seen an action property like this. But I tried the url:

```
url/index.cfm?fuseaction=security.login_check
```

which did not work either

Comment: Please mention the server side code

Comment: You need to handle redirection in your node app.

Comment: use https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle redirection in your node app. You can access redirect URL using.
`response.request.res.responseUrl`

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/799